# Integrating controller and directive for input box AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I am new to AngularJS
I have two programs written. First is auto appending input text box

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
[<span ng-repeat="input in inputs">"{{input.field}}"</span>]
<div ng-repeat="input in inputs">
    <label>{{$index+1}}</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="input.field" capitalize-first>
    <button ng-click="removeInput($index)">-</button>
</div>
    <button ng-click="addInput()">+</button>
</div>

------------------------------------------------------------
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.inputs = [];

  $scope.addInput = function(){
  $scope.inputs.push({field:''});
}

  $scope.removeInput = function(index){
  $scope.inputs.splice(index,1);
}

}]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A6G5r/134/

and second is Auto capitalization Filter using directive.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="input.field" capitalize-first>
 </div>
```

---

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('capitalizeFirst', function(uppercaseFilter, $parse) {
return {
 require: 'ngModel',
 link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
    var capitalize = function(inputValue) {
       var capitalized = inputValue.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
           inputValue.substring(1);
       if(capitalized !== inputValue) {
          modelCtrl.$setViewValue(capitalized);
          modelCtrl.$render();
        }         
        return capitalized;
     }
     var model = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
     modelCtrl.$parsers.push(capitalize);
     capitalize(model(scope));
  }
 };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = '';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YyYnM/339/

First is written using controller and another uses directive. I am not able to merge two programs and cannot understand scope of directive and controller while merging.

Can anyone suggest me how would be proper way while merging these two ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't declare modules in this way. Using a variable for module assignment isn't necessary, and creates a leaky abstraction.

Instead, you should use the module getter and setter syntax.  See this [excerpt](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#definitions-aka-setters) from John Papa's Style Guide for more information on this and other best practices.

Instead of:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
```

use:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
```

Then, in the second file (directive), you don't need to declare the `myApp` module again, merely chain onto the declaration:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('capitalizeFirst', function(uppercaseFilter, $parse) {
```